# Intuition of group parameter in Caffe Layer

Tags: caffe

I am confused about the group parameter in caffe convolution layer.

Image I have an input of `20x3x227x227` and filter size is `96x3x11x11` with `stride=4` and `padding=0`, if I set the `group=2`. Then the setting becomes:

```
group1 : 20x1x227x227, filter1: 96x1x11x11
group2 : 20x2x227x227, filter2: 96x2x11x11
```

is that correct? If that is correct, how can you concatenate them to the output `20x96x55x55`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872914/caffe-what-does-the-group-param-mean

Comment: @liangjy I saw this post but still confused.